# Getting always the same action on an A2C from stable_baselines3

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, stable-baselines, actor-critics

I'm quite new to RL and have been trying to train an A2C model from stable_baselines3 to derive an integer sequence based on 3 other input sequences of floats. I have a custom gym environment that computes the agent rewards based on the actions taken on the `step` method. Spaces are:

```
self.observation_space = spaces.Dict({
    "s1": spaces.Box(
        low=0,
        high=float("inf"),
        shape=(48,),
        dtype=np.float64
    ),
    "s2": spaces.Box(
        low=0,
        high=float("inf"),
        shape=(48,),
        dtype=np.float64
    ),
    "s3": spaces.Box(
        low=0,
        high=float("inf"),
        shape=(48,),
        dtype=np.float64
    ),
})
self.action_space = spaces.MultiDiscrete([5]*48)
```

The observables do not change based on the action, so there is not state carried over between `step` calls; for each `obs` a given `action` will maximise the reward. Then the environment would transition to the next state with a completely new `obs` that will have an unrelated new optimal `action`.

For training I run:

```
env_train = Monitor(gym.make("gym/MyCustomEnvironment-v0", data=data_train), log_dir)
model = A2C("MultiInputPolicy", env_train, verbose=0, device="cpu")    
model.learn(total_timesteps=timesteps)
```

The rewards/timesteps plot converges towards a value in a logarithmic curve. Even though when I evaluate the trained model on a new observation I always get the same set of actions.

```
env = Monitor(gym.make("gym/MyCustomEnvironment-v0", data=data_test), log_dir)
obs, _ = env.reset()
action, _ = model.predict(obs, deterministic=True)
```

Here the value of `action` will be the same or very similar regardless of the data used to create the environment (which is then used to derive `obs`). This is very surprising because the optimal policy that would maximise training rewards would be to choose different output sequences depending on the input sequence.

I have tried multiple things, including training with large datasets, changing learning rates, gamma and network topology, playing with episode lengths, etc. I have even changed the reward function to one that produces arbitrary numbers and even in that case the "trained" model will always output the same actions regardless of `obs`.

Am I just misusing A2C for a use-case it's not intended for?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am experiencing the same issue.